# Origin of term "Microbe"

Tags: meaning, etymology, terminology

What's the origin of the term **[microbe](http://www.niaid.nih.gov/topics/microbes/pages/default.aspx)**? According to related definitions and topics, I think it may be ***micro + be***. If it is, what does "be" stand for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It comes from Greek, via French.

> - microbe, etymology - late 19th century: from French, from Greek mikros ‘**small**’ + bios ‘**life**.’
> - popular name for a bacterium, 1878, from French microbe, "badly coined ... by Sédillot" [Weekley] in 1878 from Greek mikros "small" (see mica) + bios "life" (see bio-). It is an incorrect use of bios; in Greek the word would mean literally "short-lived." [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=microbe)

Therefore, literally it means **"small life"** and **"microscopic life"** scientifically speaking.

Comment: I got the impression that "microbe" is often used to refer to all "microscopic life," as you say, which would include an archæon, protozoön or fungal spore as well as the bacterium mentioned in that dictionary entry. It appears to be a synonym of "micro-organism." I guess viruses would technically be excluded by that definition. But interestingly, I found a site that lists them as a possible category of "microbes" nonetheless: http://www.microbeworld.org/what-is-a-microbe

Comment: What about micro organization?

Comment: @sumelic  In medicine we consider "microbe" any  living creature not visible to the naked eye. The word used in the scientific world  is micro-organisms, and this includes all bacteria, viruses, protozoa and fungi.  Prions, as far as I know, are still unclassified.

Comment: @Centaurus: well, there seems to be a bit of controversy about whether the definition of "living creature" should include viruses. I wrote a question about it that you'll see linked to the right of this one.